# python group by and ordered a list by another list

Tags: python, list

I wonder if there is more Pythonic way to do group by and ordered a list by the order of another list.

The `lstNeedOrder` has couple pairs in random order. I want the output to be ordered as order in `lst`. The result should have all pairs containing `a`'s then follow by all `b`'s and `c`'s.

The `lstNeedOrder` would only have either format in `a/c` or `c/a`.

input:

```
lstNeedOrder = ['a/b','c/b','f/d','a/e','c/d','a/c']
lst = ['a','b','c']
```

output:

```
res = ['a/b','a/c','a/e','c/b','c/d','f/d']
```

**update**

The `lst = ['a','b','c']` is not actual data. it just make logic easy to understand. the actual data are more complex string pairs

Comment: What do you mean a more pythonic way? compared to what?

Comment: What happens to the pairs that don't contain `a` `b` or `c`?

Comment: @M.Shaw add to the end of output list in any order

Comment: @galaxyan Does `a/b` have to appear before `a/c`? Or is it that only the first element counts?

Comment: @M.Shaw yes, second element still need to follow the same order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with customer `key` function:

```
>>> lstNeedOrder = ['a/b','c/d','f/d','a/e','c/d','a/c']
>>> lst = ['a','b','c']
>>> order = {ch: i for i, ch in enumerate(lst)} # {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
>>> def sort_key(x):
...     # 'a/b' -> (0, 1), 'c/d' -> (2, 3), ...
...     a, b = x.split('/')
...     return order.get(a, len(lst)), order.get(b, len(lst))
... 
>>> sorted(lstNeedOrder, key=sort_key)
['a/b', 'a/c', 'a/e', 'c/d', 'c/d', 'f/d']
```